# aggregate functions how to count a column and return the value in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to learn how aggregate functions work in SQL and I cant work out how to calculate the number of times a value appears within a query.

Im using **MSSQL 2008** and everything I try seems to cause an error.

Below is my query:

```
SELECT category, 
       template, 
       galleryshortDescription, 
       galleryLongDescription, 
       GalleryName,   
       GalleryTitle, 
       GalleryID, 
       GalleryCreatedDate, 
       GalleryLastUpdated, 
       GalleryPublished, 
       GalleryViews, 
       ObjectID, 
       GalleryDescription, 
       HtmlMetaKeywords, 
       HtmlMetaDescription

FROM dbo.ImageGallery
```

I would like to return the `category` field as well as the total number of times it appears in this query and I have tried using

```
count (category) AS category_counter
```

any suggestions greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `count(*) over (partition by category)`?

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to return the category field as well as the total number
>   of times it appears in this query

What you need, is to use a [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), with [`COUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) like so:

```
SELECT
  Category,
  COUNT(category) AS category_counter
FROM  dbo.ImageGallery
GROUP BY category;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5388/1)

For instance, this query will give you something like:

```
|  CATEGORY | CATEGORY_COUNTER |
--------------------------------
| Category1 |                2 |
| Category2 |                2 |
| Category3 |                3 |
| Category4 |                3 |
```

---

But you have a *big problem*, in your table.

Your table this way isn't [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you should split this table into the following tables:

**`Categories:`**

- `CategoryId`,
- `CategoryName`.

**`GalleriesProperties`**:

- `GalleryId`,
- `GalleryName`,
- `GalleryshortDescription`,
- `GalleryLongDescription`,
- `GalleryTitle`,
- `GalleryCreatedDate`,
- `GalleryLastUpdated`,
- `GalleryPublished`,
- `GalleryViews`,
- `GalleryDescription`.

**`HTMLMetas`**

- `HTMLMetaID`
- `HtmlMetaKeywords`,
- `HtmlMetaDescription`

Then your table **`ImageGallery`** would be something like:

- `GalleryId`,
- `CategoryId` a foreign key references Categories table(CategoryID),
- `Template`,
- `HTMLMetaID` a foreign key to the htmlmeta table.

This is just an example, it might needs more tweaks in your context. But you should read more about this.

Comment: SELECT  category, template,galleryshortDescription, galleryLongDescription,GalleryName, GalleryTitle, GalleryID, GalleryCreatedDate, GalleryLastUpdated, GalleryPublished, GalleryViews, ObjectID, GalleryDescription, 
                         HtmlMetaKeywords, HtmlMetaDescription, count (category) AS "category_counter"
            FROM         dbo.ImageGallery             
   GROUP BY category


but it wont return other columns as well.. i keep getting an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY and COUNT. Let's try to read: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Count(category) and group by category like this

```
SELECT  category, count(category) as ColumnNameofYourChoice
  FROM dbo.ImageGallery 
     group by category
```

When using count you have to use group by, on which, you want the count to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store category and No_of_category in Temp table. After it you can join with your table to Temp table..
Eg.

```
SELECT  category, count(category) No_Of_category
into #temp
  FROM dbo.ImageGallery 
     group by category

SELECT cat.category, t.No_Of_category,
      cat. template, 
       cat.galleryshortDescription, 
       cat.galleryLongDescription, 
       cat.GalleryName,   
       cat.GalleryTitle, 
       cat.GalleryID, 
       cat.GalleryCreatedDate, 
       cat.GalleryLastUpdated, 
       cat.GalleryPublished, 
       cat.GalleryViews, 
       cat.ObjectID, 
       cat.GalleryDescription, 
       cat.HtmlMetaKeywords, 
       cat.HtmlMetaDescription

FROM dbo.ImageGallery cat
left outer join #temp t on cat.category=t.category
```